# Problema com dialog Jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui

Tenho um `ListView` que cria alguns botões dinamicamente de acordo com IdPassoWorkflow,
e conforme o passo eu preciso apresenta uma mensagem para o usuário confirma se deseja ou não execultar a ação, 
só que a janela de dialog do `Jquery` não abre quando clicado no botão.

**`ListView` que uso para carregar os botões**

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvBotoes" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkGravar" OnClick="lnkGravar_Click" runat="server" CssClass="btnInline"
        OnClientClick='<%#Eval("IdPassoWorkflow","javascript:return CheckConfirm({0});" )%>'
        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("IdPassoWorkflow") %>'>                
        <%# TextoBotao(Container.DataItem) %></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

**Meu Jquery**

```
<link type="text/css" href="../CSS/Jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../CSS/Jquery/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/modernizr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var SqlType = '<% =vsSqlType.Value%>';
  var PassoWorkflow = parseInt(<% =vsIdPassoWorkflow.Value %>);

   function  CheckConfirm(IdPassoWorkflow) { 
    if (IdPassoWorkflow == 2)
    {
        $(function() { 
          var opcoesDialogo = {
              autoOpen: false,  
              buttons: {
                  'Não': function(event) { $(this).dialog("close"); }, 
                  'Sim': function(event) {$(this).click += new EventArgs(this.lnkGravar_Click);  }
              }
          };
          $('.EncaminharGestor').dialog(opcoesDialogo); 

          $('#lnkGravar').click(function() {
              $('.EncaminharGestor').dialog('open')
          });
      });
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Mensagem a ser apresentada.**

```
<div class="EncaminharGestor" title="Janela de Confirmação">
  <p>Encaminhar para o Gestor?</p>
</div>
```

**O Html gerado**

```
<td colspan="2" class="Button">

              <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$BodyContent$lvBotoes$ctrl0$lnkGravar','')" class="btnInline" id="BodyContent_lvBotoes_lnkGravar_0" onclick="javascript:return CheckConfirm(1);">Salvar</a>

              <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$BodyContent$lvBotoes$ctrl1$lnkGravar','')" class="btnInline" id="BodyContent_lvBotoes_lnkGravar_1" onclick="javascript:return CheckConfirm(2);">Encaminhar</a>

              <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$BodyContent$lvBotoes$ctrl2$lnkGravar','')" class="btnInline" id="BodyContent_lvBotoes_lnkGravar_2" onclick="javascript:return CheckConfirm(5);">Excluir</a>

        </td>
```

Comment: em vez de utilizar o .click, tente utilizar o .on("click" .. objetos criados dinamicamente apos a instancia do .click não tem trigger de evento, já usando o on("click" os objetos atuais e os novos receberão o trigger. não cheguei a testas, mas não custa tentar.

Comment: Fiz o teste, mas mesmo assim não abriu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está fazendo o bind de um evento no `ready` do `jquery` após a pagina já está pronta, portanto este evento nunca será executado, então remova o `$(function () { ... })` do método `CheckConfirm`.

Outro ponto, realmente não sei o que pretende fazer com `$(this).click += new EventArgs(this.lnkGravar_Click);`, isto me parece uma sintaxe valida para fazer o Bind de um evento `Server-Side` no `C#`, mas não para o bind de um evento `Client-Side` no `JavaScript`, então tente comentar o mesmo para ver se o código funciona.

```
var SqlType = '<% =vsSqlType.Value%>';
var PassoWorkflow = parseInt(<% =vsIdPassoWorkflow.Value %>);

function  CheckConfirm(IdPassoWorkflow) { 
  if (IdPassoWorkflow == 2)
  {
    //$(function() { Este bind do $(document).ready é desnecesario.
      var opcoesDialogo = {
        autoOpen: false,  
        buttons: {
          'Não': function(event) { $(this).dialog("close"); }, 
          'Sim': function(event) {
            //$(this).click += new EventArgs(this.lnkGravar_Click); Esta sintaxe não me parece valida.
          }
        }
      };
      $('.EncaminharGestor').dialog(opcoesDialogo); 

      $('#lnkGravar').click(function() {
        $('.EncaminharGestor').dialog('open')
      });
    //});
  }
}
```

Comment: Toby, a ideia do += new EventArgs era chama meu método no Server-Side mesmo assim que o usuário clicar em sim... apesar do esfosso a mensagem não apareceu na tela .

Comment: Para chamar um método no Server-Side apartir do javaScript, use o método `__doPostBack('<% this.lnkGravar.ClientID %>', '')`

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, dentro da sua funcao tem um eventlistener, tenta coloca-lo no ready do document.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="button"]').click(function(){
    CheckConfirm(2);
  });

});

function CheckConfirm(IdPassoWorkflow) { 
    if (IdPassoWorkflow == 2)
    {
        $(function() { 
          var opcoesDialogo = {
              autoOpen: false,  
              buttons: {
                  'Não': function(event) { $(this).dialog("close"); }, 
                  'Sim': function(event) {$(this).click += new EventArgs(this.lnkGravar_Click);  }
              }
          };
          $('.EncaminharGestor').dialog(opcoesDialogo); 

          $('.EncaminharGestor').dialog('open');
      });
    }
}
```

Tenta assim